# Ubuntu 15 sleeps before login

Tags: boot, suspend

I have updated from 14.10 to the recent 15.
Since I did so, everytime I am booting, it takes a lot of time in the loading screen and then the computer just goes to sleep. When I power back up, the login screen is finally visible.

Has anybody experienced something like this? Ideas?

Comment: You can press F2 during boot to see a verbose readout. You should be able to see more info on why the system is getting all hung up. Please post this info (the message listed when the system is getting hung up, such as, "waiting for network" or whatever) after doing so to help us fix your specific issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I will do it tonight and post the result. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, I did what you said and I am not seeing anything being outputted. The screen is just black and then it goes to sleep.

Then I  entered the recovery menu. In there, once I tried to enable the network the computer went to sleep just as it does when booting normally. So I am guessing that there's some problem related to that (?). Note however that once I manage to log into the system the network works fine as usual. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, I reinstalled Ubuntu 15 and the problem persisted. Even when I tried booting from USB, the same thing happened.
Solution was to reinstall Ubuntu 14. Damn waste of time :/